# Spring Cloud Stream Binder Kafka broker is not available

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a Spring Config Server application which is working with Kafka in dev environment but in local environment I keep getting:

```
{host} could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Is there any way to start the application in local environment even if the broker is not available and not get the warning logs?

The desired behaviour: If broker is not available, application should not have explicit warnings and should continue working.

I have tried to set `fatalIfBrokerNotAvailable` to false and `missingTopicsFatal` to false but it does not have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the kafka-clients (used by the binder) does not have any API to get the status of the broker(s). So there is no way to determine the state without trying to connect. Those logs are emitted by the kafka-clients code.

Comment: The binders don't use AdminClient at all?

Comment: Yes, during the topic provisioning phase, if we can't provision because the client is down, the attempt is rescheduled on a different thread every 30 seconds, but the OP wants some mechanism to prevent the logs.